# moviePlayBackDidFinish stops working

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an observer to my movieplayer, set like this.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:nil];
```

The movie played is more a background animation with sound.

For some reason, the observer for the moviePlayerDidFinish seems to stop after a while.
Any idea what might go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blush, sometimes Im such a noob.

moviePlayer.repeatMode= MPMovieRepeatModeOne; for the win. >.<

Ah well, thanks for reading though. :)